# Падает приложение при запуске

Tags: android, android-studio

logcat:

```
03-24 13:37:16.226 4898-4898/com.example.android.monopoly E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.monopoly, PID: 4898
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.monopoly/com.example.android.monopoly.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at com.example.android.monopoly.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6029)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
```

я так понимаю ошибка в `MainActivity`, вот его код:

```
package com.example.android.monopoly;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button turnBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turn_but);
        Button addBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_but);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.turn_but: addTurn() ; break;
                    case R.id.add_but: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pop.class)); ; break;

                }
            }
        };

        turnBut.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        addBut.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private void addTurn(){
        TextView TurnsScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turns_score_view);
        TurnsScore.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(TurnsScore.getText().toString()) + 1));
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/turns_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nubber of turns:"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/turns_score_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/turns_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    <view
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turn_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view"
        android:text="Next turn"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view">


    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="add action" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Что за строчка в коде приводит к нулю ? 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference'  Попробуйте прокинуть через исключение её (через блок try catch) Либо исключить ситуацию, по которой у вас возращается Null

Comment: В том то и дело что не знаю, и при запуске вроде ничего такого не вызываю( ладно бы при каком то клике(

Comment: стектрейс указывает, что проблема в разметке, добавьте ее в вопрос

Comment: Добавил разметку

Answer (score 2):

view -> View
использование xml тега вместо класса

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/view" 
    android:layout_width="1dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Попробовал заменить на `LinearLayout`, не помогло. или я что то не так понял? Чем можно заменить?

Comment: Вы в разметке заменили `<view`? А в коде на слушателе что изменили, можете продемонстрировать?

Comment: да нет жи ж. в лейауте используйте <View> вместо <view>

Comment: <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

Comment: делайте добавления и уточнениия, редактируя ответ (кнопка "править" под ответом), а не в комментариях к нему